# Deserialization of JSON and Avro without Schema

Tags: java, json, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I have been trying to implement Avro deserialization without confluent schema registry. A quick [research](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56538745/deserialize-avro-to-generic-record-without-schema) shows that I can embed the schema in header before sending the record to topic. But the schema again has to be serialized to bytes before embedding on the header which again makes this problematic. Is there anyway to achieve this?

What are what are the cons associated with this approach.

How is it possible for confluent to extract schema from the data and store it in schema registry? I understood that the schema registry embeds a schema id on the record header while sending the data to topic. Isn't the data serialized before sending to schema registry?

Again if we take a look at the Confluent [JsonDeserialzier](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/json-serializer/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/serializers/KafkaJsonDeserializer.java), it deserializes data without any schema and works with JsonNode. Why isn't a similar mechanism possible for Avro?

Comment: "I have been trying to implement Avro deserialization without confluent schema registry" Can you edit your question to include the motivation for this requirement please? It will make it easier to answer more accurately and usefully :)

Comment: @RobinMoffatt What I have been trying to create an experiement to check how can I implement avroserialization and deserialization for a POC project, and ofcourse I have can't be dealing with schemas since there are gonna be a lot. But all the examples I have seen so far has been with schema registry and I need to know how can I implement this without the need of schema registry. But as more and more I look into this schema registry becomes hard to takeway.  I would really appreciate if you could throw your thoughts on the question.

Comment: I still don't understand why you don't want to use a Schema Registry. They serve a very useful purpose.

Comment: @RobinMoffatt As I said Iam experimenting and would love to understand the low level detail

Comment: First off, there are no "headers" used for Kafka, the linked question is for Avro container files. Secondly, the Confluent serializers are open source, so you can observe how they work

Comment: @OneCricketeer Kafka absolutely has headers.

Comment: @Shermas headers aren't used for the Confluent serializers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A quick research shows that I can embed the schema in header before sending the record to topic

You can, yes. Note that the Confluent serializers do not utilize the headers, if you are following their source code.

Header values must also be strings or bytes, last I checked.

> the schema again has to be serialized to bytes before embedding on the header

Not sure what you mean "again". For every message, yes, and there's no way around that, but not within the same process of serializing a single record.

> What are what are the cons associated with this approach.

There's plenty of documentation about the pros of using a Registry. Cons include maintaining additional infrastructure and not all tools can integrate with it.

> How is it possible for confluent to extract schema from the data and store it in schema registry?

Refer [source code (extract Schema as text)](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/client/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/schemaregistry/avro/AvroSchemaUtils.java#L84) then [POST schema text to the registry to get the ID and embed in the record](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/avro-serializer/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/serializers/AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java#L103-L114)

> Isn't the data serialized before sending to schema registry?

If by "serialized", you mean as Avro, then yes, but the schema is UTF8 serialized

> JsonDeserialzier, it deserializes data without any schema and works with JsonNode. Why isn't a similar mechanism possible for Avro?

I think you should be comparing the JsonSchemaDeserializer class. Obviously plain JSON has no concept of schemas. Avro **requires** a reader schema for deserialization, but there is a similar mechanism - `GenericRecord` operates similarly to JsonNode