# Deserializing a byte[] array from a Kafka ByteArrayDeserializer into a GenericRecord or a SpecificRecord with schema

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I currently have an event stream with a Kafka topic that sends a schema-registry manager event through Java Spring Kafka. On the producer side, I'm sending with no problems:

```java
props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, IntegerSerializer.class);
props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroSerializer.class);
```

I can receive these messages without any problem by specifying the Kafka receiver as follows:

```java
props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, IntegerDeserializer.class);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer.class);
```

I already have access to the generated class Java class that is pulled from the schema registry and using this config I can deserialize no problem.

Where I am facing an issue is that I have a consumer that has to receive the message using:

```java
props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArrayDeserializer.class);
props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArrayDeserializer.class);
```

No matter what I try implementation wise, everything I face throws the following exceptions depending on implementation:
`org.apache.avro.InvalidAvroMagicException: Not an Avro data file.`
`org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Malformed data. Length is negative: -55`

This is the only prior I can find. I have tried deserialization with and without the schema and the same errors occur. I do have access to the schema at deserialization time, the same generated Java used to send the message on the producer side.

[Deserialize avro to generic record without schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56538745/deserialize-avro-to-generic-record-without-schema)

I have attached two example impls to the bottom of this post to show what has not worked:

The following has been tried with and without the specific schema, as well as deserializing to a single object vs an array of objects or to a GenericRecord:

```java
    //event is of type byte[]
LOG.info("Recieved Event: {}", event);
    LOG.debug("data='{}'", DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(event));
    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(event);
    DatumReader<SpecificSchemaObject> userDatumReader = new SpecificDatumReader<>(SpecificSchemaObject.getClassSchema());
    BinaryDecoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().directBinaryDecoder(in, null);
    List<SpecificSchemaObject> records = new ArrayList<SpecificSchemaObject>();
    SpecificSchemaObject result = null;
    try {
      while (true) {
        try {
          SpecificSchemaObject record = userDatumReader.read(null, decoder);
          records.add(record);
        } catch (EOFException eof) {
          break;
        }
      }
      result = (SpecificSchemaObject) userDatumReader.read(null, decoder);
      LOG.info("deserialized data='{}'", records);
      result = (SpecificSchemaObject) records;
    } catch (IOException ioe) {

    }
```

```java
Schema schema = WebsiteAdminEvent.getClassSchema();
    DatumReader<GenericRecord> datumReader = new GenericDatumReader<GenericRecord>(schema);
    Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().directBinaryDecoder(new ByteArrayInputStream(event), null);
    GenericRecord gr = null;
    try {
      gr = datumReader.read(null, decoder);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    LOG.info("got record: ", gr);
```

```java
    //event is of type byte[]
    List<WebsiteAdminEvent> listOfRecords = new ArrayList<>();
    DatumReader<WebsiteAdminEvent> reader = new GenericDatumReader<>();
    DataFileReader<WebsiteAdminEvent> fileReader =
        null;
    try {
      fileReader = new DataFileReader<>(new SeekableByteArrayInput(event), reader);

      WebsiteAdminEvent record = null;

      while (fileReader.hasNext()) {
        listOfRecords.add(fileReader.next(record));
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the producer used the Schema Registry, then the encoded Avro bytes are not "valid" Avro; [they start with 5 bytes that are not part of the Avro spec](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/fundamentals/serdes-develop/index.html#wire-format). The bytes also aren't Avro file container format, therefore `DataFileReader` shouldn't be used.

Ultimately, there is no reason to use `ByteArrayDeserializer`, but even if you did, that's not stopping you from manually constructing `new KafkaAvroDeserializer()` and calling its deserialize function. That class is open source if you want to see how it really works.

Comment: thanks, this helped me reach a conclusion.

Unfortunately for a reason not worth elaborating on this particular consumer was forced to use a ByteArrayDeserializer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the other answer here, I was able to manually deserialize this with the following code:

```java
public AvroObjectDeserializer(String schemaRegistryUrl, String kafkaTopic) {
    this.kafkaTopic = kafkaTopic;

    deserializer = new KafkaAvroDeserializer();
    Map<String, String> kafkaProps = new HashMap<>();
    kafkaProps.put(SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, schemaRegistryUrl);
    // tells Kafka / Schema Registry that we will be using a specific Avro type; not GenericRecord
    kafkaProps.put("specific.avro.reader", "true");
    deserializer.configure(kafkaProps, true);
  }

  @Override
  public T deserialize(byte[] data) {
    // kafka knows how to deserialize to type T via schema registry which has mapping info
    // topic -> Avro Serialized class
    final Object o = deserializer.deserialize(kafkaTopic, data);
    return (T) o;
  }
```

Comment: Why make this into another deserializer class? This will end up doing the exact same thing as setting `KafkaAvroDeserializer` in the consumer config (along with `specific.avro.reader`, which also has a constant, by the way)

Comment: In this particular implementation of a Kafka receiver I was forced to use a preconfigured byte[] deserializer only

Comment: Are you able to provide more details? You have written Java code. Therefore, you can override Consumer Properties freely, even if that means using reflection

Comment: @OneCricketeer I am forced to have this particular consumer receive bytes via a proxy (it is abstracted away from the consumer by an outdated sidecar). This isn't an issue deserializing into plain POJOs, but I needed to club this side car proxy with an avro schema.

The ultimate issue was that without a schema registry, any manual deserialization doesn't work. It requires having both the generated avro pojos, and a configured schema registry in the deserializer configs which at first was not intuitive to me.